# Is the function in the Sobolev Space W1,N?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have to show that the function $u(x)=(-log|x|)^{\frac{N-1}{N}}$ is **not** in the Sobolev space $W^{1,N}$.

> **My guess**:
>
> I have tried to show the "Trudinger's inequality" $\left( u(x)\in W^{1,N}
>  \Rightarrow \int e^{|u|^{\frac{N-1}{N}}}<\infty \right)$ does
>   not hold, therefore $u(x)$ won't be in $W^{1,N}$. But, when you
>   manipulate a little bit, you arrive to the conclusion that the
>   integral is equal to $1$, so you cannot conclude that $u(x)$ is
>   not in $W^{1,N}$.

How would you show that? Maybe obtaining the gradient ($\nabla$) of $u(x)$ and computing the integral of the modulus of $\nabla u$ to the $N$-th power to see if it is in the required space, i.e: $\int\lvert\nabla u\lvert^N<\infty$? I think it is a long path and (if I remember) you do not arrive anywhere.

Any guesses, ideas or hints?

Comment: What about polar coordinates?

Comment: The direct calculation is not difficult - the gradient is purely in the radial direction, so there's a lot of symmetry. I think you end up with something like $\int \frac 1{r \log(r)} dr$, which is infinite (assuming your domain contains a neighbourhood of $|x|=0$ or $|x|=1$).